# Ash & Novinger - Complex Variables - Defining a continuous argument, walking around the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self studying Ash & Novinger's Complex Variables. Before I present my question, here's a definition:

Let $S \subset \mathbb C$ and $f : S \to \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ be continuous. A function $\theta : S \to \mathbb R$ is said to be a *continuous argument* of $f$ if $\theta$ is continuous on $S$ and $f(s)=\lvert f(s) \rvert e^{i\theta (s)}$ for each $s \in S$.

In [Example 3.1.5 (c)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV3.pdf), the authors claim that $f : \{ z : \lvert z \rvert =1 \} \to \mathbb C$ does not have a continuous argument. They initially present a very handwavy argument and postpone its proof after they develop the necessary tools to prove it. Here's how the "handwavy proof" goes:

> The intuition underlying the above example is that if we walk entirely around the unit circle, a continuous
> argument of $z$ must change by $2\pi$. Thus the argument of $z$ must abruptly jump by $2\pi$ at the end of the trip, which contradicts continuity.

Since this is handwavy, I accept it. Later, they go on to prove that:

If $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is continuous, then $\gamma$ has a continuous argument.

I read the proof of this, it seems perfectly fine. In particular if I consider $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ is a "zerofree" continuous function and by the above theorem has a continuous argument.

This seems a little counterintuitive to me. The images of $f$ and $\gamma$ are the same. How does the "handwavy" walking around the unit circle fail in this case?

Comment: You should say your first example is for the identity map $f(z)=z$ on $S^1$; obviously the trivial map $f(z)=1$ has a continuous choice of argument on $S^1$.  The short answer is $[a,b]$ and $S^1$ are, topologically speaking, very different domains for a function.  The former is simply connected and the latter is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that $\gamma$ is applied to two different arguments (other meaning of “argument”) at the endpoints: $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(2\pi)=2\pi$. But $f$ has to make do with just one argument which “wants” to have two different values: $f(1)=0$, but we also want $f(1)=2\pi$.

In other words, as $t\to 1$ after a full circuit, $f(t)\to 2\pi$. But we’ve already assigned $f(1)=0$. With $\gamma$, you don’t have this problem as $t\to 2\pi$.

A more visual way to think about it: the domain of $f$ is a circle. If you cut the circle at 1, and add a point to the open end, you transform it topologically to the domain of $\gamma$. This transformation removes the obstacle to an argument function.